# TF10139 Error:Internal error in Changeset Comments Policy for tf checkin command

Tags: tfs, policy, checkin

I add a power shell step in my build definition(vNext). I want to execute Tf checkin command to checkin one file during the build process. We have only one Checkin policy for Mandatory checkin comments.

I started with tf checkin command and passed through some road blocks to successfully checkin my file. But i still have a warning logged in my Changeset details which says below warning message :

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.PolicyEvaluationStub   Internal error in Changeset Comments Policy. Error loading the Changeset Comments Policy policy (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.). Installation instructions:
```

Below is my command :

```
tf Checkin $source_dir  /comment:"Publish new version details" /noprompt /force /bypass /override:"Publishing Version details"
```

I tried to follow some of the links provided at [M/S Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/23001/tf-checkin-command-when-using-override-parameters.html) and [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4ba1e16-1461-48d7-85ee-594443bc9c16/checkin-notes-ignored-when-using-tfexe-as-part-of-hosted-build-process?forum=tfsbuild) . They don't provide a definite answer and say that the issue is fixed in the next build agent versions. Out TFS agents or on the latest TFS build agent version (2.117.2) so i assume the fix is already included in my agent version .

I need to get rid of this warning message in my Changeset details.Below is the screenshot

[Warning message in Changeset details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NzNJ.png)

Appreciate any help here.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested at my side with the `Agent.Version 2.117.2`, the `PowerShell` step failed, but the changes are checked in successfully.

The issue is fixed in `Agent.Version 2.122.1`.  I tested with the `Agent.Version 2.122.1`, it's working without any error.

So, you can download and install the `Agent.Version 2.122.1` or later version from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases), then try it again.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tested with the latest version and it worked. My testing with agent 2.122.1 is in progress . Are you aware if there is any lower version than 2.122.1 which has this fix included

Comment: Sure Andy. Thanks for the support provided.

Comment: Version 2.122.1 fixed the issue